# Can Facebook block your comments for everyone except you?

Tags: facebook

A friend told me he posted a comment onto a Facebook page's status update today.  I went to that Facebook page, and looked at all the comments on the status update, but I did not see his comment.  He told me he could see his comment, so I'm wondering if Facebook has a feature that can let a page admin prevent others from seeing someone's comment while still letting that person see his own comment, so that he doesn't know it was hidden?

Comment: Yeah, the page admin is probably hiding his comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://allfacebook.com/hide-comments-again_b97330) says that Facebook does give page administrators the option of hiding a comment, which makes it invisible to everyone except the commenter and his friends.  When a page administrator hides a comment, the following message appears on the administrator's screen:

> You've hidden this comment so only the person who wrote it and their friends can see it.  Undo this or delete this comment.
>
> You can also Report it as abusive, or Ban [name].

This means the page admin must have hidden my friend's comment.  (The reason I didn't see his comment is because I wasn't *Facebook friends* with my friend at the time - we sometimes defriend each other so we can see how the privacy settings are working.)